# This program for pythagorean triplet gives complex numbers for some cases

Tags: python

This program for finding pythagorean triplet returns complex numbers in some cases.

```
x=int(input("enter side 1")) #inputs sides 1
y=int(input("enter side 2")) #and 2
z=((x**2)+(y**2))**(1/2) #applying pythagoras' theorem (see image 1)
if z%1==0:
    print(z,"is the missing side")
elif z%1!=0:
    k=((x**2)-(y**2))
    import math
    math.fabs(k) # see image 2
    a=k**(1/2)
    print(a,"is the missing side")
```

Image 1 (when sides are 4 and 5):

[image: when sides are 4 and 5]

Image 2 (this is the code itself):

[image: this is the code itself]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you (not) want the complex numbers? What cases is this good/bad thing happening in?

Answer (score 0):

`fabs` doesn't modify its argument; `math.fabs(k)` accomplishes nothing.

You want

```
import math
k = math.fabs(x**2 - y**2)
a = k ** (1/2)
print(a,"is the missing side")
```